# iOS app store always auto updates after unplugged from charger

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, ios-appstore, charging

My iPhone always updates its apps every morning after I unplugged it. I have a pretty regular daily schedule and I want it to update while it's still on charger.

I have an iPhone 7 on the most up-to-date iOS 15.5 at the time when this question was asked. In settings > battery usage the App Store activity actually says, "Connected to charger". I have auto App Updates and Optimized Battery Charging on.